# Combobox selected item background at top not popup

Tags: c#, wpf

I am looking for a way to set image background there.. Because it is white on a gray background.. Selected item trigger doesnt work because there is no parent ComboboxItem..

[image]

```
      <ComboBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
                    <Border x:Name="border"  Padding="10">
                        <Image  Source="{Binding }" Stretch="None"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
                    <WrapPanel  Width="{Binding ActualWidth , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                             AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox }}}"  Background="{StaticResource ListItemSelected}"  Orientation="Horizontal"   IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ComboBox.Resources>
```